# Schema global describe map keyset

Tags: apex, schema

I have a doubt regarding the Schema.getGlobalDescribe() method which returns a Map.. I know that Schema.SobjectType is the Api names of Sobjects.. But I am not able to understand what does the keys of this Map represents!?Also Can anyone explain the difference between Sobject class and Schema.SobjectType class in Apex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is the name of the type as a string. This lets you write logic using a string for the type, and then find out later if the type exists by seeing if there is a map value for that map key. This would typically be done in code that is configurable or that at run time discovers the types.

The `SobjectType` is a token from which an `Sobject` class can be created:

```
SobjectType t = Contact.SobjectType;
Sobject s = t.newInstance();
```

or from which descriptive information about the type can be obtained:

```
DescribeSObjectResult d = t.getDescribe();
```

Think of `SobjectType` as the starting point object for code that wants to work for multiple types. In code where the types are fixed, you will rarely need to use it.

See the [SobjectType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm) documentation.

By the way, you can get the `SobjectType` from an `Id` or from an `Sobject` - both have a `getSObjectType()` method. So, for example, if you had a collection of `Id` values you could work out the set of types involved:

```
Set<SobjectType> types = new Set<SobjectType>();
for (Id id : ids) {
    types.add(id.getSObjectType());
}
... types.size() ...
```

An example of using the map:

```
SObjectType t = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('FeedItem');
if (t != null) {
    // Code that requires chatter to be turned on
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. Can you please provide an example which requires the type discovery at run time? I want to know the scenario in which I will need to check whether the SobjectType exists for a given String name!? Thanks

Comment: @AkshitGupta I've added an example scenario. More often needed inside a managed package that has to be designed to work in a variety of org configurations. Once-off code can be hardcoded to assume the org configuration.